# where is ANS X9.31 used?

Tags: rsa

[FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) mentions two standards for RSA: PKCS #1 and ANS X9.31. PKCS #1 is used with SSH, X.509, etc. What is ANS X9.31 used with?

FIPS 186-4 has the following line:

> ANS X9.31, Digital Signatures Using Reversible Public Key Cryptography for the Financial
>   Services Industry (rDSA), was developed for the American National Standards Institute by the
>   Accredited Standards Committee on Financial Services, X9

So maybe it's used in proprietary finance applications? Are there any open standards that actually use it?

Comment: Maybe compliance with FIPS 186-4 implies ANS X9.31 compliance.